# Subset time series by groups based on cutoff date data frame

Tags: r, time-series

I have a data frame with time series data for several different groups.  I want to apply different start and end cutoff dates to each group within the original data frame.

Here's a sample data frame:

```
date <- seq(as.POSIXct("2014-07-21 17:00:00", tz= "GMT"), as.POSIXct("2014-09-11 24:00:00", tz= "GMT"), by="hour") 
group <- letters[1:4]                           
datereps <- rep(date, length(group))                  
attr(datereps, "tzone") <- "GMT"
sitereps <- rep(group, each = length(date))    
value  <- rnorm(length(datereps))
df <- data.frame(DateTime = datereps, Group = group, Value = value)
```

and here's the data frame 'cut' of cutoff dates to use:

```
start <- c("2014-08-01 00:00:00 GMT", "2014-07-26 00:00:00 GMT", "2014-07-21 17:00:00 GMT", "2014-08-03 24:00:00 GMT")
end <- c("2014-09-11 24:00:00 GMT", "2014-09-01 24:00:00 GMT", "2014-09-07 24:00:00 GMT", "2014-09-11 24:00:00 GMT")
cut <- data.frame(Group = group, Start = as.POSIXct(start), End = as.POSIXct(end))
```

I can do it manually for each group, getting rid of the data I don't want on both ends of the time series using `![(),]`:

```
df2 <- df[!(df$Group == "a" & df$DateTime > "2014-08-01 00:00:00 GMT" & df$DateTime < "2014-09-11 24:00:00 GMT"),]
```

But, how can I automate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just merge the cuts into the data frame, and then create a new data frame using the new columns, like below. `df3` contains the removed records, `df4` contains the retained ones.

```
df2 <- merge(x = df,y = cut,by = "Group")
df3 <- df2[df2$DateTime <= df2$Start | df2$DateTime >= df2$End,]
df4 <- df2[!(df2$DateTime <= df2$Start | df2$DateTime >= df2$End),]
```

Comment: OK, what if you wanted to do something similar, but this time instead of deleting data, just flag rows that are _within_ a particular date time frame (once again given by start and end dates)? I asked a new question here [Create column to flag rows within a date period in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42516632/create-column-to-flag-rows-within-a-date-period-in-r/42516781#42516781)

Comment: @notacodr In that code, we are subsetting a data frame using a vector of true and false statements. So if you wanted to just created a flag that was TRUE when something was inside the range, and FALSE otherwise, you could do this: `df2$flagvar <- !(df2$DateTime <= df2$Start | df2$DateTime >= df2$End)`

Comment: Yep, I like it. Thanks!