# Create column to flag rows within a date period in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I need to create a "flag" column within my main data frame that flags rows where the date is within a specific time range.  That time range comes from a second data frame.  I think I'm just stuck on the ifelse (or if) statement because there are NA's in the flag column.  Maybe ifelse isn't the way to go.  Here's some sample data:

```
    # main data frame
date <- seq(as.Date("2014-07-21"), as.Date("2014-09-11"), by = "day") 
group <- letters[1:4]                           
datereps <- rep(date, length(group))                  
groupreps <- rep(group, each = length(date))    
value  <- rnorm(length(datereps))
df <- data.frame(Date = datereps, Group = groupreps, Value = value)  

# flag time period data frame
flag <- data.frame(Group = c("b", "d"), 
        start = c("2014-08-01", "2014-08-26"),
        end = c("2014-08-11", "2014-09-01"))

# Merge flag dates into main data frame
df2 <- merge(df, flag, by = "Group", all.x = T)

# Execute ifelse statement on each row
df2$flag <- "something"
df2$flag <- ifelse(df2$Date >= as.Date(df2$start) & df2$Date <= as.Date(df2$end), "flag", "other")
```

The result is that in rows where a "start" and "end" date are specified, "flag" and "other" are labeled, but where "start" and "end" are NA, I get Na values for `df2$flag`. This happens even when I initiate `df2$flag` with `"something"`. I want `"other"` for all values that are not defined as `"flag"`.  Look at rows 50:68.

```
df2[50:68,]
```

Comment: When you say "doesn't work", is R throwing an error, or is it returning something that is not what you intended?

Answer (score 1):

If I was doing this I'd skip the intermediate dataframe (`df2`) and the merge step and use ifelse with `|` which means OR.

```
date <- seq(as.Date("2014-07-21"), as.Date("2014-09-11"), by = "day") 
group <- letters[1:4]                           
datereps <- rep(date, length(group))                  
groupreps <- rep(group, each = length(date))    
value  <- rnorm(length(datereps))
df <- data.frame(DateTime = datereps, Group = groupreps, Value = value)
```

This applies `flag` to the criteria you specified:

```
df$flag <- ifelse(df$DateTime >= as.Date("2014-08-01") & df$DateTime <= "2014-08-11" |
                    df$DateTime >= as.Date("2014-08-26") & df$DateTime <= "2014-09-01", 
                  "flag", "other")
```

Then you can have a look:

```
df[df$flag=="flag",]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response boshek. However, this method doesn't take group into account. I also need to use the dataframe "flag" because I have many differing start and end dates by groups and I don't want to manually type those dates into an ifelse statement.

Answer (score 0):

Change your last line to:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df2)) {
    if (is.na(df2$start[i])) {
        df2$flag[i] = 'other'
    } else if (df2$Date[i] >= as.Date(df2$start[i]) & df2$Date[i] <= as.Date(df2$end[i])) {
        df2$flag[i] = "flag"
    } else {
        df2$flag[i] = "other"
    }
}
```

Its ugly but it does the job. This code is not vectorized, so its fine for your situation, but would be slow for larger applications.

Comment: Sorry about that error in the example.  I just updated it and am still having the issue.

Comment: In that case you are going to have to use something other than the ifelse() function. You are trying to compare two date objects and if one of them is not a date (like NA), it is going to return NA. You may want to write a custom function to do this and then apply it to the flag column using sapply(), or map_chr() from the purrr package.

Comment: This does work.  Another solution avoids the loop and also makes us of `is.na` indexing: 
`df2$flag <- NA
df2$flag <- ifelse(df2$Date >= as.Date(df2$start) & df2$Date <= as.Date(df2$end), "flag", "other")
df2$flag[is.na(df2$flag)] <- "other" # replace NA's with "other"`